# How to detect month/year change

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am using the `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` to detect when the day changes:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dayChanged:", name: UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification, object: nil)

@objc func dayChanged(notification: NSNotification){

}
```

Inside the `dayChanged` handler I want to test if the new day is the first day of a new month or first day of the new year.

I should test if `NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: NSDate()).day` is equal to 1, but how to differentiate between month and year ?

Comment: Subtract one day and check if it is 31/12 ?

Comment: Check if month is first - then you have new year, if not then you have new month, simple as that.

Comment: @sunshine: I like that, you can added as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if month is first - then you have new year, if not then you have new month.